# How do I customize the biblatex entries in Texmaker's bibliography menu?

Tags: biblatex, texmaker

I use Texmaker on Linux and am very happy with it.

I would like to customize the Biblatex entries in the Bibliography menu, though. They don't include a lot of fields that I need, which somewhat defeats the purpose of having the menu in the first place, since I end up manually entering the missing fields.

Example: the article entry looks like this:

```
@article{•,
author = {•},
title = {•},
journaltitle = {•},
year = {•},
}
```

volume, number, pages and date are all missing. For Bibtex, these are included as OPT fields that can be removed with "clean" command from the Bibtex submenu.

I figure there has to be an easy way to customize this. I tried searching the xml config files, but didn't find anything but the settings that can already be configured through Texmaker's menus and settings tools.

Comment: May be you can post this question in https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to solve this problem by not using Texmaker to handle my bibtex database at all.

I have discovered JabRef, which supports biblatex as of version 2.7. I am a convert. Using JabRef is much easier, and it is very powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the fields are hard-coded in the sources, so there's no way to customize them at the moment. Maybe you can ask the developers to add support for some kind of templates editable by the user.